# Merge Text/Fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

One feature/need for my application is that I have an audit trail for certain tables. This is something that I have done many times in the past using different languages. So far I have been able to come up with the idea of using an Observer to monitor changes to the model/table. This works exactly as expected. The issue I am having is with string manipulation/querying specific data.

I have a string such as this `{{user.created_by}} changed {{user.id}}'s First Name from {{user.first_name_was}} to {{user.first_name}}`

The main issue I am trying to solve is what would be the best way to convert a string to an object/attribute definition?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by converting a string to an object/attribute definition? Like, User.find_by_name(some_name_string) would get the User object with the name some_name_string assuming name:string is a column for the users table.

Comment: I have a model named User with an attribute created_by. What I am trying to figure out is how I can use the string {{user.created_by}} to pull data from the model.